# Extraer un numero de una cadena de texto

Tags: sql, oracle, regex

Necesitaría saber como extraer el valor 1, por ej. de este texto

P93 - HOLA 93 - 1 - ABC

Solo necesito tener en una columna ese numero, el tema es que tengo
muchos casos de texto y no me devuelve cualquier cosa.

Ejemplos:

003 - PALANCA - 3 - ABC ---> De aquí necesito el 3 antes de - ABC

P93 - HOLA 93 - 1 - ABC ---> De aquí necesito el 1 antes de - ABC

AP3 - ALTO PAKIRMO PATIO COMITUS - DF  ---> Aquí nada o Null

MER - AV. GYVERTADOR 748  - HORLO - 2 - DF  ---> De aquí necesito el 2 antes de - DF

Usando lo siguiente, conseguí en algunos casos el valor que necesito,
pero en muchos no. Por ejemplo en P93 - HOLA 93 - 1 - ABC

```
SELECT 
regexp_substr('TEXTO', '\d+',5)
FROM DUAL
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Por favor, mejora el formato de tu pregunta: es difícil comprender el resultado obtenido y el esperado. Además, ¿la expresión regular es para Oracle, SQL Server o ambos?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 2):

Podrías obtener el resultado esperado usando:

- Creando un expresión regular para validar el formato y extraer el valor

  ```
  ^.+- (\d+) -.+$
  ```
- [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#sthref1001) para validar que la cadena cumpla el formato.
- [CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/expressions004.htm#sthref808) para que en caso que el formato no sea válido, devolver `null`
- [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm#sthref1608) para extraer el valor en la cadena.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(field, '^.+- (\d+) -.+$') 
         THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '^.+- (\d+) -.+$', '\1') 
         ELSE NULL END AS "value"
FROM table
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ecdd8f0c3a783e7a23f4f9e3c492b984)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Si todos los números que necesitas están seguidos de un espacio en blanco  y guion por los dos lados esto debería funcionar

```
        SELECT 
         regexp_substr('TEXTO', '- \d+ -',5)
        FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Para el caso `003 - PALANCA - 3 - ABC`, el resultado obtenido seria `- 3 -`. Estas cerca, solo falta _"limpiar"_ la cadena.